# How to install and boot on a RAID 5 Configuration?

Tags: installation, 10.10, raid

I've been trying for a couple of days now to get Ubuntu 10.10 installed on a RAID 5 setup. I have 3 1TB drives so I also need Ubuntu to boot off of one of those drives. From what I've been able to find on the forums I need to set one of the drives to have a RAID 1 partition that I can use for /boot but I have no idea how to do that(something about using Gparted?). I'm farily new at this so a step-by-step would be awesome but I'll take any help I can get.

Answer (score 2):

I finally resolve the software RAID-5 issue on the DELL R310.

The article just mislead us
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID

Workaround Steps for software RAID-5

1. Remove all existing RAID settings, LVM setttins
2. Create partition with 20G on each disks
3. Set the first disk's 20G partition to use as root '/', install your whole OS into it.
4. Configure the RAID-x for the rest of your partitions.

Done, hope you get over of it!!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create a /boot partition anymore.  You do need to use the alternate/text mode installer.  At the partitioning step, create a partition on each disk and set its usage to raid, then create the raid array and assign it to be used for the root ( / ).

Comment: According to Ubuntu's [Reliable Raid](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReliableRaid) wiki it might not be such a good idea? Does anyone happen to know the current state of affairs?

Comment: @j-g-faustus the current state is as I said, since at least 10.04.

Comment: I don't understand how this would work. Your system needs to be able to read boot files before Ubuntu has loaded. But if you're using software RAID, you need Ubuntu to load before you can have access to any boot files.

Comment: @Phil, The grub2 core understands software raid and can load the kernel from it.  The core itself is loaded by the bios from a single disk, where it is typically embedded in the few unused sectors following the MBR.